# Excel VBA - "Run-time error '13' Type mismatch"

Tags: excel, vba

I am a relative novice at VBA. I am attempting to flag keyworded cells (ColumnA) in excel using a list of keywords (ColumnC), which will output a flag into ColumnE.

Here is a visual example of the dataset:
[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BoKv.jpg)

When I attempt to run this code, I am presented with the error:
"Run-tume error '13': Type mismatch" popup.
On selecting debug, the field selected is line 17: s = Cells(i, "A").Value

I am using this code from another StackOverflow query: https://superuser.com/questions/1228098/find-keywords-in-paragraphs-of-text-in-excel

Within the "Watches" portion of the debugger it shows the following information: "expression s = Cells(i, "A").Value", "Value ", "Type Variant/Integer".

Can anyone help me find what is preventing this code from executing?

```
Sub KeyWord_II_TheSequel()
    Dim Na As Long, Nc As Long, ary, s As String
    Dim r As Range, a, i As Long, outpt As String

    Na = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nc = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim ary(1 To Nc)
    i = 1
    For Each r In Range("C1:C" & Nc)
        ary(i) = r.Text
        ary(i) = " " & ary(i) & " "
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    For i = 1 To Na
        s = Cells(i, "A").Value
        s = " " & s & " "
        outpt = ""
        For Each a In ary
            If InStr(1, s, a) > 0 Then
                outpt = outpt & "," & a
            End If
        Next a
        If outpt = "" Then
        Else
            Cells(i, "E").Value = Mid(outpt, 2)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You are going to need to see what value is in the cell. One easy way to do this is let your code run into the error, then while in debug mode, type into the immediate window: `?Cells(i, "A").Value`, hit enter and see what you get. Or, just figure out which row `i` is on and look at the Ai cell on the sheet. Since your `s` is a string, and you are getting this Type mismatch error, that usually means the value in the cell is some kind of error (usually caused by a formula that is evaluating to an error like `#N/A`)

Comment: When you debug after the error, hover your mouse over the i variable to check its value  land hover over cells() to check its value.